# Why won't my fonts load anywhere but in Chrome localhost?

Tags: css, sass, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've got a font-face that won't load *anywhere* but on localhost on Chrome. When I upload the files to a [live server](https://henrikfalck.netlify.com/) or open localhost in another browser like Safari it won't load.

**Example:**
[Left side is Chrome on localhost, right side is Safari on localhost.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APgO6.png)

I've gone through my code dozens of times already, checked that my file structure is correct, downloaded the fonts again to check if they were corrupt, and made sure that my font-family are the same.

---

### Files:

**_fontface.scss**

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Ortica-Light";
  src:
   local("Ortica-Light"),
   url("/src/styles/fonts/Ortica-Light.woff2") format("woff2"),
   url("/src/styles/fonts/Ortica-Light.woff") format("woff"),
   url("/src/styles/fonts/Ortica-Light.ttf") format("ttf"),
   url("/src/styles/fonts/Ortica-Light.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**_typography.scss**

```
$headings: "Ortica-Light";

h1, h2, h3 {
 font-family: $headings; //"Ortica-Light"
 font-weight: normal;
}
```

**base.scss**

```
@import "_fontface.scss";
```

**File structure**

```
src
├ components
└ styles
  ├ _fontface.scss
  ├ _typography.scss
  ├ base.scss
  └ fonts
    ├ Ortica-Light.otf
    ├ Ortica-Light.ttf
    ├ Ortica-Light.woff
    └ Ortica-Light.woff2
```

---

When I go to another browser and open localhost or open my live link in any browser (Chrome included) and open DevTools to check the files I get [font files that doesn't look anything like the font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIqcb.png).

Comment: Does the browser Developer Tools give any error?

Comment: Not anymore, no. Had some earlier, but those got fixed.
I've made a slight error on that part in the post, I'll edit it.

Comment: They are, yeah. Now all of a sudden I'm getting two errors; `Failed to encode downloaded font: <URL>` and `OTS parsing error: invalid version tag`.

Comment: I think you mean `Failed to decode downloaded font`? If so, then that usually means that there is an issue with the font itself.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant _decode_, yeah. Thanks, I'll have to take a look.